# ObjectDataSource paging and extra parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, paging, objectdatasource, custompaging

I'm using an ObjectDataSource to sort/page/filter as below:

```
        <asp:ObjectDataSource 
                ID="odsCompaniesIndex" runat="server" EnablePaging="true"  
                   SelectMethod="GetCompaniesSubset" 
                   StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex" 
                   MaximumRowsParameterName="maximumRows"
                   SelectCountMethod="GetCompaniesCount" 
                   SortParameterName="sortExpression" 
                   TypeName="Company">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlStatus" 
                 ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" 
                 DbType="Boolean" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="status" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The gridview consuming the ObjectDataSource:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvCompanyIndex" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsCompaniesIndex"
        AllowPaging="true" DataKeyNames="company_id" AllowSorting="true">
    </asp:GridView>
```

I want to pass in a number of parameters like the one above into SelectParameters. The method call 'GetCompaniesSubset' executes but on the return I get the following error:

> ObjectDataSource 'odsCompaniesIndex'
>   could not find a non-generic method
>   'GetCompaniesCount' that has
>   parameters: status.

My SelectMethod is:

```
    public DataSet GetCompaniesSubset(
        int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, string sortExpression, bool status)
{...}
```

How do you allow the SelectMethod to utilise StartRowIndexParameterName/MaximumRowsParameterName and any extra parameters?

Thanks

Comment: How do you consume your `ObjectDataSource`? Are you using a `GridView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that **`GetCompaniesCount`** does not have `status` parameter, not `GetCompaniesSubset`.

Comment: Thanks I saw this yesterday and thought how could I be so stupid! I need to read more!